# Dialect for SQL2005

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate.

We are migrating one of our existing web application which uses Hibernate 3 and SQL 2000 server to SQL 2005 server.

Can I get help about which version of Hibernate to use with SQL 2005 as I could not find any dialect for SQL 2005 in Hibernate 3.0.5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the dialect recognizes the difference between SQL Server years; it's all just Microsoft SQL Server.

Which JDBC driver are you using?  Microsoft's or jTDS?  You only get the features that the driver supports.

And you shouldn't be using database specific features.  Your code isn't portable that way.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the reply.

The issue is solved. The dialect is not the problem.

We had to fix the database.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the standard SQLServer dialect (org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect) for SQLServer 2005 and I got no issues so far.
I'm using the JTDS JDBC Driver.

I'm also using the Schema Generator, no problems so far.